# How to write the necessary java class to use gson.fromJson() for the following json object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to parse the following JSON object:

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": {
          "subkey1": {
                "subsubkey1": "value",
                "subsubkey2": "value"
           },
           "subkey2": {
                "subsubkey1": "value",
                "subsubkey2": "value"
           }

          ...........other dynamic subkeys..............
    }
}
```

I tried the following:

```
public class MyObject{
    String key1, key2;
    KEY3 key3;

    public class KEY3{



        public class SUBKEY{
            String subsubkey1;
            String subsubkey2;

            //getters and setters
        }
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

and then did the following:

```
MyObject mObject = gson.fromJson(jsonMessage, MyObject.class);
```

where `jsonMessage` is the JSON string above and subkeys are dynamic so i do not know how many of them are there.. But `key3` becomes `null`. So, my problem is, how can I get `key3` and its subkeys and subvalues using `gson.fromJson`? I do not want to do it like the following:

```
JSONObject jObject= new JSONObject(jsonMessage);
JSONObject key3Object = jObject.getJsonObject("key3");
```

I want to use `gson.fromJson();` directly.

Comment: `string` should be `String`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg sorry that is just a typo

Comment: Ain't subclasses supposed to be static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with three different POJO classes that is exact replica of this JSON string.

```
class MyObject {
    private String key1, key2;
    private KEY3 key3;
}

class KEY3 {
    private SUBKEY3 subkey1;
    private SUBKEY3 subkey2;
    // getters and setters
}

class SUBKEY3 {
    private String subsubkey1;
    private String subsubkey2;
}

...

MyObject data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

output:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": {
    "subkey1": {
      "subsubkey1": "value",
      "subsubkey2": "value"
    },
    "subkey2": {
      "subsubkey1": "value",
      "subsubkey2": "value"
    }
  }
}
```

---

If keys are **dynamic** and JSON string is not known in advance then try with `Map<String,Object>` using [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html)

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to write that subkeys are dynamic so i do now know how many subkeys there are. Edited the question

Comment: have a look at last part.

Comment: One thing i do not understand, i do not have any json file, i have a string and i can create json object from that string, so do i have to create a file, write json string into it and read it?

Comment: you can pass json string directly instead of reader object. code updated as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need two instance variables in KEY3 called subkey1 and subkey2 of type SUBKEY.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to write that subkeys are dynamic so i do now know how many subkeys there are. Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine. Provided the key3 class should have fields subKey1 & subKey2. Eg

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

class MyObject {
    String key1, key2;
    Map<String, SUBKEY> key3;

    public class SUBKEY {
        String subsubkey1;
        String subsubkey2;

        public String getSubsubkey1() {
            return subsubkey1;
        }

        public void setSubsubkey1(String subsubkey1) {
            this.subsubkey1 = subsubkey1;
        }

        public String getSubsubkey2() {
            return subsubkey2;
        }

        public void setSubsubkey2(String subsubkey2) {
            this.subsubkey2 = subsubkey2;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "SUBKEY [subsubkey1=" + subsubkey1 + ", subsubkey2="
                    + subsubkey2 + "]";
        }
    }

    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1 = key1;
    }

    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public Map<String, SUBKEY> getKey3() {
        return key3;
    }

    public void setKey3(Map<String, SUBKEY> key3) {
        this.key3 = key3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyObject [key1=" + key1 + ", key2=" + key2 + ", key3=" + key3
                + "]";
    }
}

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonMessage = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\",\"key3\":{\"subkey1\":{\"subsubkey1\":\"value\",\"subsubkey2\":\"value\"},\"subkey2\":{\"subsubkey1\":\"value\",\"subsubkey2\":\"value\"}}}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyObject mObject = gson.fromJson(jsonMessage, MyObject.class);
        System.out.println(mObject);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to write that subkeys are dynamic so i do now know how many subkeys there are. Edited the question

Comment: If subkeys are dynamic you could use Map<String, Subkey>. As explained by user3218114. I've updated my answer anyway. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're just confused with nested classes and inner classes. The inner class (without `static` in definition) is some class, which instances always have "parent" instance. As for nested classes (with `static`), they're independent on the "parent" class and that's what we need in the case. So, the solution would be so:

```
public class MyObject {
    String key1, key2;
    Key3 key3;

    public static class Key3 {

        public static class Subkey {
            String subsubkey1;
            String subsubkey2;    
            //getters and setters

        }
    }

    //getters and setters

}
```

For the better clarification, you should look at this thread: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=135